# Cloudn't register-PSRepository in my Windows10 for installing Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I want to install Azure PowerShell in my windows 10, but I met an error message, I tried to find the reason for the error and found there was no package when I ran **Get-PSRepository**.

Background: 
Install azure with code as below:

`Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope AllUsers`

`Install-Module -Name Az -Repository PSGallery -Force`

Error message:

Can't find the package at **C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1748**

`Register-PSRepository -Default`

`Get-PSRepository` shows can't find the package.

`net winhttp show proxy` shows without proxy server

what should I do to install the azure PowerShell?

Comment: Could you please try to install PowerShellGet with `Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Repository PSGallery -Force`? And then you can check if it is installed with `Get-InstalledModule`

Comment: @JackJia I tried it and there was an error message of **Get-PSGarrleryApiAvailability: PowerShell Gallery isn't avaliability now.**

Comment: Please check my answer. Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message, it seems that you have connection issue to [powershell gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/)

So, my first suggestion is to check your network environment work. Also remember to check your system proxy settings.

If your network has no problem, you may [download package manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-packages/manual-download?view=powershell-6) and then [install modules from the downloaded nuget package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-packages/manual-download?view=powershell-6#installing-powershell-modules-from-a-nuget-package)

Another choice is to use [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview)

Hope the above could be helpful to you!